# primefaces p:column sortby String List

Tags: primefaces, columnsorting

when a p:dataTable loop an Object List, it is very easy to use `SortBy` method in a `p:column` by use the Object's attribute. like this:

```
<p:dataTable var="o" value="#{bean.theObjectList}">
    <p:column headerText="herderText" sortBy="#{o.objectAttribute1}">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{o.objectAttribute1}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

public class Bean {
    private List<TheObject> objectList;

    public class TheObject {
        private String objectAttribute1;

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

click button like [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/sort.xhtml):

but if I loop a `Primitive List` which not like `Object` has some attributes, how can I SortBy it in p:column by click button?

```
<p:dataTable var="o" value="#{bean.stringList}">
    <p:column headerText="herderText" sortBy="?">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{o}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

public class Bean {
    private List<String> stringList;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Slightly improved the formatting.

Comment: why? usually we dont have only one column in table